# Where did they find Gold?

Tags: logical-deduction, knowledge

A lesson in US Colonial history. ( A stretched version)

After the thirteen colonies declared independence they needed resources badly. So the enterprising brave pioneers of those times set out to find wealth in the whole US territory. Especially precious materials.

> They found lead in Colorado.
>
> They found zinc in Massachusetts.
>
> Which colony did they find Gold in?
>
> And Aluminium?
>
> And what did they find in Pennsylvania?

Logical Explanation please.

Comment: Was gold found in a colony or simply a state? I ask because Colorado is not one of the original 13 colonies.

Comment: Yes. Colorado was just a land then. The puzzle logic is very different than your thinking.

Comment: -1 You ask for a logical deduction, but the answer you accepted is a non-sequitur. There's no rational reason that wordplay based on the initials of the colonies' names would cause different metals to be present in them. https://xkcd.com/1562/

Comment: Maybe add a [cipher] tag?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It looks like the thirteen colonies

> used rot13, translating letters 13 places, to find their resource as,
>  rot13 (CO) → Pb (lead)
>  rot13 (MA) → Zn (zinc)

For Gold, Aluminium, and what did they find in Pennsylvania?

> rot13 (Au) → NH / New Hampshire
>  rot13 (Al) → NY / New York
>  rot13 (PA) →  Cn which may represent numbers of carbon, such as diamond, graphite or especially in Pennsylvania, carbon based coal. Thanks to SteveV.
>  <sub>Original try for Cn: it is the symbol for chemical element Copernicium with atomic number 112. A single atom of it was first created in 1996, and a further atom in 2000. It has an extremely short half-life and isn't a viable answer.</sub>

Comment: please think about Cn more. Can you logically find it?

Comment: rot13(Creuncf gurl sbhaq P, juvpu ner qvnzbaqf be v fhccbfr, pbny)

Comment: Thanks @SteveV - your suggestion makes the most sense I can think of.

Comment: They found New Mexico and Arizona inside eachother...

Comment: AND Georgia and Tennesse

Answer (score 6):

Partial answer:
They found lead in Colorado.

> Lead is PB, Colorado is CO. Reverse PB to get BP, add one to the first letter and take one from the second.

They found zinc in Massachusetts.

> ZN, reversed is NZ, take one from the first letter and add one to the second to get MA

So by similar rules:
Gold was found in

> AU, reversed is UA, becomes TB or VZ - Veracruz?

Aluminium in

> AL -> LA -> MZ or KB .... nope

In Pennsylvania they found:

> Boron: BO -> OB -> PA

Comment: Although this is not my answer, you are kind of on the right track

Comment: Element #65 is Terbium.

Answer (score 3):

Credits to @Tom for the logic and solutions until New York

“It looks like the thirteen colonies

> used rot13, translating letters 13 places, to find their resource as,
> rot13 (Co) → Pb (lead)
> rot13 (Ma) → Zn (zinc)

For Gold, Aluminium, and what did they find in Pennsylvania?

> rot13 (Au) → NH / New Hampshire
> rot13 (Al) → NY / New York”

Pennsylvania:

> Following @Tom’s rot13 logic, they found CN, which is cyanide.

Comment: That's a compound.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: Yes it is.  But the question only says "resources" not "elements".